# possible to unzip this latin-encoded file on a utf8 locale within R?

Tags: r, encoding, compression, unzip

is there an easy way to access the files in this archive using only R and CRAN packages?  i am hitting this issue on [a macOS github action running R](https://github.com/asdfree/pof/blob/master/.github/workflows/r.yml).  thanks!

```
dictionary_tf <- tempfile()

dictionary_url <-
    paste0(
        "https://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Orcamentos_Familiares/" ,
        "Pesquisa_de_Orcamentos_Familiares_2017_2018/Microdados/Documentacao_20230713.zip"
    )

download.file( dictionary_url , dictionary_tf , mode = 'wb' )






dictionary_files <- unzip( dictionary_tf , exdir = tempdir() )
# Error: Error in unzip(dictionary_tf, exdir = tempdir()) : cannot open file '/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T//RtmpGf7urj/working_dir/Rtmpvh3H5G/Cadastro de Locais de Aquisi<87><c6>o.xls': Illegal byte sequence
# Execution halted



library(archive)
dictionary_files <- archive_extract( dictionary_tf , dir = tempdir() )
# > dictionary_files <- archive_extract( dictionary_tf , dir = tempdir() )
# Error: Error: archive_extract.cpp:188 archive_write_header(): Can't create 'Cadastro de Locais de Aquisi<87><c6>o.xls'
# Execution halted
```

Comment: `unzip(..)` worked fine for me (ubuntu-23.04, R-4.2.3), no errors

Comment: thanks, yes, works on windows for me as well..

Comment: Have you compared the (e.g.) md5 or sha256 checksum of the downloaded file between macos and windows to verify that the download itself is not corrupting the file?

Comment: might not be corrupted since it's properly showing the name of the problem-file:  `'Cadastro de Locais de Aquisi<87><c6>o.xls'` ?

Comment: hm not so sure about that Anthony! I've download things many times which failed on my Mac (e.g. through my laptop going to sleep) and the filename is still the same